# проверка условиz увеличения или уменьшения value trackbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть два trackbar как при увеличении trackbar1.Value,сделать что бы trackbar2.Value уменьшалось ?
*и наоборот при уменьшении trackbar1 что бы увеличивался trackbar 2

Answer (score 0):

```
private int valueBefore = 0;
    public void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Draw(trackBar1.Value);
        if (trackBar1.Value < valueBefore)
        {
            if (trackBar3.Value >= trackBar3.Maximum)
            {
                trackBar3.Value = trackBar3.Maximum;
            }
            else trackBar3.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (trackBar3.Value <= trackBar3.Minimum)
            {
                trackBar3.Value = trackBar3.Minimum;
            }
            else trackBar3.Value--;

        }
        valueBefore = trackBar1.Value;
    }
```